# "namespace ‘package’ x.x.x is already loaded, but >= y.y.y is required" errors even after reinstalling all packages

Tags: r, devtools, cran, install.packages

I am trying to download and install the caret.ts R library from GitHub. When I tried to install it it said:

```
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace ‘cli’ 2.3.0 is already loaded, but >= 2.4.0 is required
```

so I manually deleted the "cli" folder from my libraries folder and reinstalled it, only to be greeted by the same message about another package. After repeating this process three times, I made a single-column dataframe of all folders present in my libraries folder via command prompt ("dir > files_and_folders.txt" plus some editing in Excel), then deleted all folders from my libraries folder and reinstalled them all using the following code:

```
rm(list=ls())

lapply(names(sessionInfo()$otherPkgs), function(pkgs)
  detach(
    paste0('package:', pkgs),
    character.only = T,
    unload = T,
    force = T
  ))

.libPaths("C:\\Users\\Me\\Documents\\R\\R_libraries")

libraries <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\Me\\Documents\\R\\R_libraries\\Libraries.csv")

str(libraries)
#'data.frame':  245 obs. of  1 variable:
#  $ LIBRARY: chr  "abind" "askpass" "assertthat" "automap" ...

for (library in libraries$LIBRARY) {
  install.packages(library)  
}
```

After around an hour or so of occasionally clicking "yes" to popups, the packages were all reinstalled.

So I ran:

```
devtools::install_github("sfeuerriegel/caret.ts")
```

and received the error message:

```
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace ‘cli’ 2.3.0 is already loaded, but >= 2.4.0 is required
```

How do I ensure that when I install packages they are all up-to-date?

(If I try install.packages("cli") etc. it just gets stuck in a loop of asking me to restart the R session over and over again and not actually installing anything.)

Comment: First the yes/no pop-ups were asking you whether to install from source. Unless you are on linux, it would be advisable to just click no. Also check the loaded libraries. dettach all the libraries that are not base then install without restarting

Comment: Do you have an `.Rprofile` file that automatically loads packages at start up?

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, you may have old versions of packages installed by the admin/root user that cannot be upgraded by your user.

Running `.libPaths()` will show you the locations where R packages are:

> [1] "/home/myuser/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2" "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"
> [3] "/usr/lib/R/site-library"                       "/usr/lib/R/library"

One alternative, not sure how safe, is to make your user the owner of the folder where the library causing the issue is. For example, in a terminal:

`sudo chown myuser:myuser /usr/lib/R/library/ * -R`